# Jquery Character Counter for Dynamically Added Text Boxes

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically adding text fields on a button click using Jquery.  I need to add a character counter underneath each text field that gets added, so as the user types they can see how many characters are left.

Right now, what it does is display the div element, but it's treating each text field with the same character countdown, rather than counting the characters in each text field. I have attempted to use .each and .map to loop through the updateCounter div tag, but continue to get the same results. How can I improve this to report the character counter on each textfield?  Thanks-

This Fiddle illustrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/7com4vqz/1/

HTML:

```
<input type='button' value='+' id='addUpdate'>
<input type='button' value='-' id='removeUpdate'>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>        
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <h4>Update #1</h4>
        <textarea id="txtUpdates1" name="txtUpdates1" cols="130" rows="5" maxlength="500" class="form-control" placeholder="500 characters max"></textarea>
        <div id="updateCounter1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
//Dynamically added updates.
var counter = 2;
$("#addUpdate").click(function ()
{
    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<h4>Update #' + counter + '</h4>' +
    '<textarea cols="130" rows="5" maxlength="500" class="form-control" placeholder="500 characters max" name="txtUpdates"' + counter + '" id="txtUpdates' + counter + '" value="">');
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

    var newCounter = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'updateCounter' + counter);
    newCounter.after().html('<div name="updateCounter"' + counter + '" id="updateCounter' + counter + '" value="">');
    newCounter.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

    counter++;
});

$("#removeUpdate").click(function ()
{
    if (counter == 1)
    {
        alert("No more textboxes to remove");
        return false;
    }

    counter--;

    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
});


$('body').on('keyup', '[id^=txtUpdates]', function ()
{
    var max = 500;
    var len = $(this).val().length;

    if (len >= max)
    {
        $('[id^=updateCounter]').text(' you have reached the limit');
    }

    else
    {
        var char = max - len;
        $('[id^=updateCounter]').text(char + ' characters left');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7com4vqz/2/)

I only had to add an attribute on your `textarea` and then update your jQuery to:

```
$('body').on('keyup', '[id^=txtUpdates]', function ()
{
    var max = 500;
    var len = $(this).val().length;

    if (len >= max)
    {
        $('#' + $(this).attr('data-id')).text(' you have reached the limit');
    }

    else
    {
        var char = max - len;
        $('#' + $(this).attr('data-id')).text(char + ' characters left');
    }
});
```